# The map $N\rightarrow N^N\bmod (2N+1)$ and the number $13612$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Recently, i've been experimenting with the map $N \rightarrow N^N \bmod (2N+1)$. What i would do is repeated apply this map to some numbers. There's a lot of cycles with this map, but i found a particularly massive one:

$13612, 15106, 27724, 27553, 29074, 53239, 76162, 135319, 103369, 201064, 323761, 202351, 24889, 15556$

This cycle has a period of $14$. It is very long and i couldn't find any other cycle that is nearly as long as this one (and not for lack of trying). The best i could find are $2$ cycles of length $7$:
$$554782, 923989, 578686, 1081525, 827113, 1001092, 634036$$
$$603229, 661333, 1166386, 1343245, 1772455, 1085395, 1819786$$

Can anyone prove or disprove the claim that the cycle starting with $13612$ is the largest cycle there is?

Comment: It's essentially a random walk, with an approximately equal chance of going up or going down. That it eventually cycles is not surprising, but regardless of your test results, I see no good reason to believe that there is a maximum possible cycle length.